# How to check jboss running in redhat environment?

Tags: linux, jboss, redhat, jboss6.x

I have installed jboss-eap-6.2.0 in redhat environment and started the server.But i'm not able to access the home page via http://<>:8080 .Here i have to access home using ip address or name like http://<>:8080 its getting time out. So i would like to know what is the problem here and why not to see the jboss home here ?

```
1.Is there any way to check the server running in putty command line ?
2.Able to install the software connecting via ip but same ip is not allowing to access jboss page .So is firewall blocking the port 8080 ?
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the standalone.xml file from the `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` directory.

Look for **all the** texts `jboss.bind.address` in there and change the ip with the server's IP address so that you can access it from your local pc.

For example

```
${jboss.bind.address:192.168.1.68}

${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.1.68}

... and so on...
```

Also, you can look for the loop back ip address(`127.0.0.1`) in the xml file as well and replace it.

Comment: I changed it to <interface name="public">
 <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:130.211.118.86}"/>
        </interface> .and tried to access it from web browser.. not working

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced same issue wheni installed jboss7 on centos machine.i found that 8080 port was being used by some other app,thus disabling jboss7 to use that port.

-you can 
  **telnet localhost 8080** (or) ps -ef|grep java
  to check if jboss is running

if its running properly and you still not able to connect through your browser

- use **nmap** to check services running on that port
- you can edit your port configuration at
        **jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml**

  run jboss again

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the default interface in socket-binding as well in your standalone.xml.